# AAD app encounter AADSTS50000 with prompt=admin_consent

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Today when I request for a code of AAD app in OAuth flow, the server returns:

> error:server_error
>
> error_description:AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token or an issue with our sign-in service. Trace ID: c81bb57b-7f96-4f96-9003-13c54b9aa700 Correlation ID: 4303257a-9f95-4298-b8e8-8ea72c696557 Timestamp: 2019-12-17 07:19:35Z
>
> error_uri:https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50000

However afer I remove the `prompt=admin_consent` from my request query, it works.

This is my original query:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx&
prompt=admin_consent&
scope=openid&
response_type=code&
nonce=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx&
redirect_uri=https://my.php&
resource=https://graph.windows.net
```

More information:

- Rest of my AAD apps work fine if I do not request for admin_consent
- This query was broken today, I still use this since last week.
- The same query works in Germany(https://login.microsoftonline.de) and China(https://login.chinacloudapi.cn) endpoin

---

2019 / 12 / 18

update more infromation

Now I found that this fail might happen in different browsers and OS

this is my statistics

- X    - Google Chrome version 79.0.3945.79    windows 10 - 1903
- X    - Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0     windows 10 - 1903
- X    - Firefox 71.0（64 bit）              windows 10 - 1903
- O    - Chrome version 76.0.3809.132      Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12
- X    - Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 70.0.1 Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12
- X    - IE 11.0.9600.19540                    Windows 7 SP 1
- X    - Firefox 70.0.1                        Windows 7 SP 1
- X    - Chrome 79.0.3945.88               Windows 7 SP 1
- O    - chrome Version 79.0.3945.79         Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- X    - Chrome 79.0.3945.88                   Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- O    - Firefox 71.0                      Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- X    - Chrome version 79.0.3945.79           Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- O    - Firefox 71.0                      Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

---

More information about this,

After I remove the SharePoint application permissions of my app, it can successfully login without error AADSTS50000

> [image]

---

2019 / 12 / 24 Updated

Received from MS support

> “Acknowledging that there seems to be a bug/regression here. Hit count is low, and unfortunately our telemetry does not contain enough information to pinpoint the problem.
>
> Given low hit count and the need to add debugging telemetry, this issue likely will not be resolved till late Jan/early Feb.”

Thank you for help.

Comment: Is this happening for all of your app's customers? Or only in one tenant?

Comment: You're passing `prompt=admin_consent` twice (last line and 3rd line)

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret, This is hapening to my azure tenant which register this kind of app, other different O365 domains fail to use OAuth flow login. And the query had worked for a year.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, sorry to mistype this query, I  request the query without the last prompt=admin_consent parameter

Comment: @JimXu, Thanks for this document, but this query had worked for more than a year, and it works at different regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mail communication with MS support for a week, this problem is comfirmed and fixed by Microsoft

Brief description of the content from the mail:

- The issue is fixed and applied patch on 2018/12/31
- The issue caused by a bug when MS deployed a application permission related feature, bu there is no official bug id or reference.
- The affected region included all Non-English registered tenant.
- All of my tenants now work properly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes#aadsts-error-codes), you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already raised a support for this issue :), but now there is no clear answer for this.

Comment: @吳文喬 If you get the answer for this, please share it here.  This will be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.